# Keyboard disappearing shows white color- Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am developing a chat application.For adjusting the chat entry with keyboard, I used

```
 App.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().
    UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

It works fine. But the problem I am facing is whenever we hide the keyboard, it is not that smooth.ie; It shows some white color and closes.Please refer the attached GIF.

[image]

When I changed to

```
UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Pan);
```

It will solve the issue but, keyboard will overlap the entry. How to solve this? How to make the keyboard disappearing smooth like in whatsApp? Any help is appreciated.

For more clarity please find the video URL:https://drive.google.com/file/d/16g8oVzOkQ0fxd66zOfc97D4TI80B1VKe/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: According to your code and screenshot, I can not reproduce your issue when I use App.Current.On<Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize); in ContentPage OnAppearing method, so can you provide sample at github, I will help you to test.

Comment: I didnt provide it in onAppearing. I Used it in MainActivity

Comment: Please check this sample https://github.com/tvm-anand/StackOverflowWorkout.git

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Bro..did you got any solution?

Comment: I download your sample to test, but I have no issue about keyboard, then I also don't see any issue about your gif. I want to upload gif, but have some issue, I will upload my gif for you tomorrow.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Hi, Please find the video link https://drive.google.com/open?id=16g8oVzOkQ0fxd66zOfc97D4TI80B1VKe

Comment: please take my gif:https://github.com/CherryBu/gif/blob/master/20.gif

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Bro , then what will be the issue? :(  Will it be something related to XF  version ?

Comment: Can you try your project in another device and see if there is still having issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I done a workaround for this problem. The white color is due to the background color of theme in android. I changed the background color of my default theme in styles.

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">#576775</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87176/windowsoftinputmode-doesnt-work-in-xamarin-forms-android

Maybe second post in this discussion will help

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I tried that solution. But it didn't solved the issue.